# Getting the organization name from the Force.com Identity Service?

Tags: salesforce

Using OAuth2 and REST with a custom created Remote APP, I can successfully get the user info from the [Force.com Identity Service](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#The_Force.com_Identity_Service), however it only returns the Organization ID, not the Organization Name. This is an example packet similar to the one I get:

```
{
"id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D50000000IZ3ZEAW/00550000001fg5OAAQ",
"asserted_user":true,
"user_id":"00550000001fg5OAAQ",
"organization_id":"00D50000000IZ3ZEAW",
"username":"user@example.com",
"nick_name":"user1.2950476911907334E12",
"display_name":"Sample User",
"email":"user@example.com",
"status":{
    "created_date":"2010-11-08T20:55:33.000+0000",
    "body":"Working on OAuth 2.0 article"
},
"photos":{
    "picture":"https://c.na1.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/F",
    "thumbnail":"https://c.na1.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/T"
},
"urls":{
    "enterprise":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/{version}/00D50000000IZ3Z",
    "metadata":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/{version}/00D50000000IZ3Z",
    "partner":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/{version}/00D50000000IZ3Z",
    "rest":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/",
    "sobjects":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/sobjects/",
    "search":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/search/",
    "query":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/query/",
    "recent":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/recent/",
    "profile":"https://na1.salesforce.com/00550000001fg5OAAQ"
},
"active":true,
"user_type":"STANDARD",
"language":"en_US",
"locale":"en_US",
"utcOffset":-28800000,
"last_modified_date":"2011-01-14T23:28:01.000+0000"
}
```

How can I send a query (possibly SOQL) with the Organization ID to get the Organization Name? I would like to get back a JSON response with data outlined in [this data format](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm).

I am using CURL through PHP to get this far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are referring to the Organization object.  It has an attribute called Name.
[From this doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm):
Organization.Name:  The name of the organization

You can do a REST call to get this information.  [From this doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/api_rest.pdf)

curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v27.0/sobjects/Organization/00D50000000IZ3ZEAW?fields=Name -H "Authorization: Bearer **token**"

Edit:  Corrected spelling of "Organization".

Comment: Except for Organization being misspelled in the link, it worked like a charm. +1

Comment: Oops!  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've corrected the original post.